# Joomla 2.5 slow after migraration to a dedicated VPS

Tags: k2, mysql, migration, performance, server-response-time

Recently I migrated a joomla 2.5 site with K2 from a shared host to a dedicated web server with WHM/cPanel with 1 GB of RAM. I used migration procedure recommended by WHM and everything went fine. My problem is now that the website loading is very slow, much slower than on the busy shared server!

Time to first byte is 7 to 10 seconds! But this is only the case for joomla pages. If I put a static page, it loads in a little fraction of a second. What I have on the home page is intro of 15 newest articles in the main section plus tag cloud, 15 most read item titles and things like this in modules. I tried to reduce this numbers to just 1 and then the website loads in just 2-3 seconds. It seems the load time increases gradually with number of items being loaded, either in the main section or in the modules. So I guess there is something wrong with MySQL server configuration? I have MySQL 5.5.42 and database type in joomla configuration is mysqli, the same as before on the shared hosting.

Could anybody advice on this please?

Comment: Your Joomla site and mysql is on same hosting server?

Comment: @SD. yes, they both are on the same VPS.

Comment: Thant means, in your joomla configuration the mysql host server is `localhost`... is this correct? if this is not the scenario and you are using IP address then try with `localhost` as host name.

Comment: Yes, it is already set to `localhost`.

Comment: It's hard to say based on the information you give. Are you using the same server environment? PHP version is the same, etc? Check your server error logs and see if they provide some more information.

Answer (score 1):

It all lies in your php.ini file. When you have shared hosting it is adjusted properly..on VPS it is your duty to change settings accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

If you have cache enabled, try to disable it and clean the cache..
If it solves the problem use File cache instead.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the plugins/System-Page Cache is enabled. We had similar issues recently on 2.5 and 3.0 sites migrated to a VPS. The cache actually slowed them on the old server but on the new VPS they were far more responsive when enabled. JCH cache plugin is also pretty effective.

Answer (score -5):

Shared Hosting are usually faster than VPS hosting.. Anyway to fix temporairly your proble, just move the joomla installation to a subdirectory instead of the root folder. This works I can't explain why but works.

Comment: I'm interested in why you think shared hosting is usually faster than VPS hosting. Could you provide some more information?